# SQL where if not

Tags: mysql

I have a table of etrade transactions. i want to

```
SELECT symbol, sum(shares), (price * shares) as cost, sum(total) as total
FROM transactions_orig
WHERE type = 'EQ' AND IF(transaction = 'dividend', shares <> 0, ??)
GROUP BY symbol
HAVING sum(shares) > 0
```

so i only want to include the row if the transaction type is dividend and the shares are not equal to 0.. which means the dividend was reinvested and not paid in cash.
if the transaction equals dividend and the shares equal zero.. ignore the row.

I'm sure I'm over thinking this.. but i can't figure it out. Below is some example data

```
1. Dividend   EQ        LGCY        0        114.00   0.00
2. Credit     UNKNOWN               0          9.99   0.00
3. Bought     EQ        BBEP      100      -1978.99  19.69
4. Dividend   EQ        T           0        157.50   0.00
5. Dividend   EQ        T           4.42686 -157.50   0.00
6. Adjustment UNKNOWN               0        -90.00   0.00
```

What I'm trying to exclude is rows like row 4 (where the dividend is paid) but include row 5 (where more shares are purchased)

Comment: Why are you showing us dates?

Comment: no reason i just copied 6 rows of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand your requirement. You need to select all transaction but exclude dividend with zero shares.

Format your where clause from

```
WHERE type = 'EQ' AND IF(transaction = 'dividend', shares <> 0, ??)
```

to

```
WHERE type = 'EQ' AND ((transaction = 'dividend' and shares <> 0) OR transaction <> 'dividend')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT symbol, sum(shares), (price * shares) as cost, sum(total) as total
FROM transactions_orig
WHERE type = 'EQ' AND transaction = 'dividend' and shares <> 0
GROUP BY symbol
HAVING sum(shares) > 0
```

Comment: i only want to include the rows where transaction equals dividend and shares <> 0. so if the transaction was split and shares were equal zero it would still include it